# Is there a difference between using DECLARE and passing values to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any difference between these two different ways of calling stored procedures? How does it effect parameterization?

```sql
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @ixMachineType int = 1
DECLARE @ixMachineModel int = NULL
DECLARE @dblRpm float = NULL
DECLARE @iOffset int = 0
DECLARE @PageSize int = 10


EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[uspGet_MachineModel] 
   @ixMachineType
  ,@ixMachineModel
  ,@dblRpm
  ,@iOffset
  ,@PageSize
GO
```

and

```sql
EXECUTE [dbo].[uspGet_MachineModel] 1, NULL, NULL, 0, 10
```

Comment: Well of course there is a difference, at least in the way you code it. ;) The procedure itself is parameterized. The difference here is how you get values to those parameters. In the grand scheme of things these two are basically the same. The only real difference is in the first one you capture the return val, but in the second you don't.

Comment: When you declare the variables, you have full control over the types.

Comment: If you need to pass the result of a function call like getdate you need to use variables as this can't be passed inline. Otherwise rarely any practical difference

Comment: @gordon regardless of what data type you declare the variables they will still end up being whatever data type expected by the proc when received by it

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . I should have been more precise that no implicit conversion needs to take place.

Comment: It still has to potentially convert it from whatever literal representation you are using on the RHS of the assignment when assigning to the variable. So I dont see much difference to getting this when assigning to the params inline.